# Why is my server causing a syntax error when deployed to Heroku but runs with no errors locally (using Create React App, Node/Express)?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, create-react-app

**Edit to add picture of exact error, and to provide more info**

[image: This is the error I see in the console. Total typical syntax error. But this error does not appear in development, only after building and deploying.]

When I click on main.35...js in the error message in the console, it shows me the source code to my index.html, all of it with the red underline, but I don't see the erroneous syntax there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"><title>BoGoodSki.com</title><link href="/static/css/main.4d5a52c0.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.35eb4822.js"></script></body></html>
```

Also, in development, there is no error or warning in VSCode regarding the index.html file.   I'm confused for sure.

Thanks for the help so far!

**End edit**

I have an app deployed to Heroku that has been working well.

Today I made some changes to the Express server to handle a simple API post request to a MongoDB instance on mLab.  I had to set up CORS policy as middleware but, otherwise, I didn't make any substantial changes to the server code.

My deployment flow has been to run 'npm run build' on the Create React App client, and then use the Heroku CLI to git push from my server folder.  This process has worked well.  Until today.

Now, when I deploy to Heroku, it says that it publishes successfully, but the app is blank in the browser and the console says that there is a syntax error of < in the build JS file.  I can't currently reproduce the error because I rolled back to a working deployment in Heroku.

Here is my server code.  Can you identify what may be causing the issue?  My JS build files sit in client/build/static, just like Express expects them to, so I don't know what's up.

Appreciate the help.

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('./config/config');
require('./models/FormData');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);

const app = express();

const FormMessage = mongoose.model('formMessages')


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.post("/submitMessage", (req, res) => {
    var newMessage = new FormMessage(req.body);
    newMessage.save()
        .then(item => {
            res.status(200).send();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send();
        });
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    const path = require('path');
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
    });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

Comment: What is the exact syntax error and on what line of code?  Also, what version of node.js is running on Heroku (see what `node -v` tells you)?

Comment: @jfriend00 I can't reproduce the error at the moment without crashing my app on Heroku.  So I don't have the exact syntax error on hand. And it references my JS build file so, main.35eb4822.js.  And it just says line 1, but the code is minified to 1 long line for build, so it doesn't provide a lot of help.  Sorry I don't have a lot of details.  Tomorrow morning when I'm less burnt out from the issue, I'll redeploy to Heroku quickly, get more details while the error is present, and then roll it back.Oh, also: node: 9.2.1.  Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Well, I hope you can see how frustrating it is for us here when you post there was a syntax error and you don't tell us what the error was.  To debug, you need to make a non-minified build and run that and hopefully get a more meaningful error message.  I rather doubt we can "guess" what the error is.

Comment: @jfriend00 I get your frustration.  And I apologize.  Part of the reason that I thought this question might be answerable in this form is because I was thinking it may have been a common error that I just wasn't adequately searching for and it might be something in my server code that someone more experienced than me would see immediately.  I'll provide as much info as I can in the morning.  And, seriously - sorry for the frustration, I appreciate your willingness to help.

Comment: Did you check the node version on Heroku?  Oh, and there is NO reason to minify server-side code.  It just complicates troubleshooting and does not have the benefits that client-side code gets from minifying.

Comment: I have 8.1.1 identified in the engines object of my package.json. Could that be an issue. Also, the syntax error in the console, from my memory, just said "Unexpected token  <", like a common error like that, except it referred to line one of build file and that error doesn't exist before building. I get all the info I can in the morning. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 .  I added more info describing the error.  In regards to minifying the code, when I run "npm run build", it automatically minifies it as per the default Create React App settings, from what I can tell.  I can edit that workflow if necessary to help identify the issue.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!!

Okay.  Here are the steps that I took.  I'm not sure which, individually, resolved the problem.  But, altogether, they worked.

First, I deleted the existing main.35...js file in my source code direetory.  Actually, I deleted the entire build/static folder. And then ran "npm run build" in the client directory to rebuild the React app.

I changed the node engine in my package.json from 8.1.1 to the version I am running locally, 9.2.1.

In my index.js, I removed the conditional regarding the production environment variable because, it occurred to me that it didn't make sense to serve it up differently locally than I would in production; I think that conditional was a remnant from something I had been working on earlier in the project.

Those steps taken together have done the trick. I appreciate all who have viewed this question and given it any thought.  Thanks!